# How to postpone default form action after jquery ajax call finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this form:

```
<form class='setPricetInput' method='post' action='mos.php'>
<label>
<span class = 'boldFont'>Your Selling Price:</span>
<input type='text' class='moneyFormat reqPrice' autocomplete='off' name='b2'>
</label>    
<button class='setPriceButton'>set</button>
</form>
```

And this jquery click function:

```
$(".setPriceButton").click(function(){
$this = $(this);
var $thisForm = $this.parent();
var $detailLine = $this.next(".detailLine");
var buyOrderID = $detailLine.find('.orderID');    
var priceSet =ParseFloat($thisForm.find('.reqPrice').val().replace('$','')).toFixed(2);
var sendData = {'value': buyOrderID, 'type': 'Buy_Order_ID'};
$.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData);        
var sendData = {'value': priceSet, 'type': 'Price_Set'};
$.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData);
})
```

I want the default form action (mos.php) run after the jquery click function. The jquery code adds values to _SESSION and it is needed for mos.php to run correctly. How can I postpone the default action to after the jquery function finishes?

Comment: You can catch the Ajax successfully submitted call and simply override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the default submit on a form you need to run `.submit()`. Normally we would just put this in a callback, but since you have 2 ajax calls running we need to make sure **both** are finished before we submit the form. To do this we make a variable and a function outside the `.click` scope. Next we make a function that is going to run when each of the `$.getJSON`'s are done. Now the first time the function runs it will check to see if the `firstFinished` is set to `true`, if it's not then it will set it to `true` so that the second call will submit the form. This way if the first `$.getJSON` request comes back **after** the second one you will have no issues.

```
var firstFinished = false,
    getJSONDone = function(){
        if(!firstFinished){
            firstFinished = true;
            return false;
        }

        $('.setPricetInput').submit();
    };

$(".setPriceButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    var $thisForm = $this.parent();
    var $detailLine = $this.next(".detailLine");
    var buyOrderID = $detailLine.find('.orderID');    
    var priceSet =ParseFloat($thisForm.find('.reqPrice').val().replace('$','')).toFixed(2);
    var sendData = {'value': buyOrderID, 'type': 'Buy_Order_ID'};
    $.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData, getJSONDone);        
    var sendData = {'value': priceSet, 'type': 'Price_Set'};
    $.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData, getJSONDone);
});
```

Comment: looks like the best solution. do I need to prevent default inside the click function?

Comment: @user2395238 yes you do, I've updated the answer to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.getJSON()` call back function to submit form.

```
    $.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData,function()
    {
        //call this another one
          $.getJSON('url','data',function()
           {
               //in the last,make form submit.
              $( ".setPricetInput" ).submit();
    }
    );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: The problem is there is multiple $.getJSON and I want to submit the form after all of them are finished.

Comment: You can call cascading getJSON() and in the last getJSON() callback,submit form. I've edited soultion.Try once